# Increase volume of audible warnings

Tags: kia, warning-sound

2017 Kia Sorento SX, how do I increase the volume on audible warnings like the lane departure warning? I can barely hear any of the audible warnings

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I found an online edition of the [Owner's Manual](https://www.kia.ca/content/ownership/ownersmanual/16sorento-en.pdf) (2016 version), but it doesn't have anything in it about changing the volume level of the chime or audible warnings. Nothing is popping up in my Google searches, either. My suggestion to you at this point is to check with your dealer to see if that is even an option.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My owners manual didn't have anything about it either. I couldn't  find anything online, but you guys seem to have answers that no one else can find. Thanks again